# how to insert a Dictionary into an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am quite new to iOS and Objective-c. 
I am trying to auto generate a `pList` in my app that looks like this.

[image]

I've so far been able to create the file making it a normal `Value => Key` file if i replace my for loop by

```
for (NSString* exercisePictureName in bigPictureData) {

        [data setObject:exercisePictureName forKey:exercisePictureName];

    }
```

but my problem is that I have no idea how to structure the logic at the end of my loop to create a file structure like shown in the picture. As it has to be exact.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to structure my loop so that it creates the file with the right format????

```
- (void) createImageListFromSource {


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"exercisePictures.plist"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"exercisePictures.plist"] ];
    }


    //To insert the data into the plist
    NSArray* bicepPictureData = [self getAllimagesThatStartWith:@"bicep-"];
    NSArray* tricepPictureData = [self getAllimagesThatStartWith:@"tricep-"];
    NSArray* absPictureData = [self getAllimagesThatStartWith:@"abs-"];
    NSArray* chestPictureData = [self getAllimagesThatStartWith:@"chest-"];
    NSArray* backPictureData = [self getAllimagesThatStartWith:@"back-"];

    NSArray* bigPictureData = [bicepPictureData arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tricepPictureData];
    bigPictureData = [bigPictureData arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:absPictureData];
    bigPictureData = [bigPictureData arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:chestPictureData];
    bigPictureData = [bigPictureData arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:backPictureData];

    NSArray* finalData = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString* exercisePictureName in bigPictureData) {

        NSDictionary* data = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:exercisePictureName,@"text",exercisePictureName,@"image", nil];
        [finalData arrayByAddingObject:data];
        NSLog(@"%@",data);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",finalData);
    [finalData writeToFile: path atomically:YES];

}
```

Comment: `NSMutableArray` would be better choice for the `finalData`...

Comment: +1 for nice screen shot showing desired plist structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is an array of dictionaries. Pseudocode to show the structure:

```
 NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array];
 for (...) {
     NSDictionary* d = @{@"image": something, @"text": somethingelse};
     [arr addObject:d];
 }
```

When you are all done, just save the array directly with `writeToURL...`.